# Using the arrows to navigate the textboxes in a DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that uses DataGridTextColumns to display some data, some of which I want to be able to change. Everything works well, except using the arrows to navigate it. If I select a cell and move with the arrows, it all works fine, but I want to do the same with the TextBoxCell.
What I did have, and worked, was going through the visual tree with VisualTreeHelper and getting the next cell and selecting the TextBox; however, it was very, very long code given that I had to process each key separately. Given that cells already process the event in this way, I tried this:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            var temp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tb);
            var cell = temp as DataGridCell;
            while (cell == null) {
                temp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(temp);
                cell = temp as DataGridCell;
            }
            if (tb == null)
                return;
            cell.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```

But whenever I use the keys, nothing happens. The event just gets skipped. The code runs all the way to the RaiseEvent, but when that method gets called, nothing happens. 
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else runs into it, the problem was the event. DataGridCell doesn't handle PreviewKeyDown, only KeyDown. The solution is to manually create the event and send it to the cell. Take into account that if you fail to put the event as handled, it will fire twice. Complete code follows;

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb != null && isControlKey(e.Key)) {
            var temp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tb);
            var cell= temp as DataGridCell;
            while (cell== null) {
                temp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(temp);
                cell = temp as DataGridCell;
            }

            if (tb == null || cell== null)
                return;
            var target = cell;
            var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;

            if (tb.Text.Trim().Length == 0) //Just a check for the value
                tb.Text = "0";

            cell.RaiseEvent(
                new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(cell), 0, e.Key) {
                    RoutedEvent = routedEvent
                });
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```